# Why can't range be printed? Defined is prime function wrong?

Tags: python, range

```
def isprime(a):
    sum = 0
    x = 1

    if(a % x == 0):
        sum += x
    x += 1

    if (a + 1 == sum):
        return True
    elif (a + 1 != sum):
        return False

    return True

for num in range (1, 101):
    if(isprime(a) == True):
        print(a)
```

Comment: def isprime(a):
    sum = 0
    x = 1

    if(a % x == 0):
        sum += x
    x += 1

    if (a + 1 == sum):
        return True
    elif (a + 1 != sum):
        return False

    return True

for num in range (1, 101):
    if(isprime(a) == True):
        print(a)

Comment: I don't know what you think `isprime()` is trying to do, but it's not even close to a working primality test.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop variable is `'num'`, not `'a'`:

```
for num in range (1, 101):
    if isprime(num):
        print(num)
```